# pyplot.scatter: How does one set color of points from low --> high?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just discovered [pyplot.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) and have been playing with it a bit. I'm having trouble interpreting my results due to the coloring. For example, given my 3 (a,b) sized data arrays **dataX**, **dataY**, and **dataMag**:

```
import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.scatter(x=dataX.flat, y=dataY.flat, vmin=np.min(dataMag),
            vmax=np.max(dataMag), c=dataMag.flat, lw=1, s=1)
plt.show()
```

It would be really helpful if there was a way to set the low values in **dataMag** (i.e. 0) to white and have the colors gradually increase to the maximum color of black, or red, or whatever i don't care. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the kwarg `cmap`.

```
 plt.scatter(...,cmap='hot')
```

Taken from [the scipy cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps):

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import outer
rc('text', usetex=False)
a=outer(arange(0,1,0.01),ones(10))
figure(figsize=(10,5))
subplots_adjust(top=0.8,bottom=0.05,left=0.01,right=0.99)
maps=[m for m in cm.datad if not m.endswith("_r") ]
maps.sort()
l=len(maps)+1
for i, m in enumerate(maps):
    subplot(1,l,i+1)
    axis("off")
    imshow(a,aspect='auto',cmap=get_cmap(m),origin="lower")
    title(m,rotation=90,fontsize=10)
```

well generate a figure with all the color maps available with your installation. The name with '_r' appeded on the end will give you the same map, with the colors in the opposite direction.

It is also possible to define your own custom color maps

Comment: There is a typo in line `maps=[ ...`. A missing `)` at the end

Comment: I don't seem to have the string `'cubehelix'` as a cmap... Is that version dependent?

Comment: I am not sure which version it got added in (but it is my favorite cmap).  http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~dag/CUBEHELIX/ .  I will change it to something more boring.

Comment: Wow, interesting cmap! Thanks for the link. (Removing my old python now... :)

Comment: @tcaswell Wow...so it would seem...I'll take a look. Thanks. I'll leave this open a bit before giving u the answer.